# Which image is accurate viz insat or meteostat?

Tags: satellites

I regularly watch both the above said satellite images for India, particularly for chennai. I notice there is lot of difference between the two. Which one is accurate to foresee the rains ?.Generally, I observe and correlated the actual rains with the satellite picture of meteostat is nearly  coinciding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between Meteosat and Insat satellite Images](http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/7537/difference-between-meteosat-and-insat-satellite-images)

Comment: Although it is a duplicate question, the answers to the other question do not actually answer this question but mainly give links to further information.